# Save numpy array of Python lists

Tags: list, numpy, nested, save

I'm trying to replicate the format of an existing data file which has the following class structure when loaded with `np.load`:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    <class 'list'>
        <class 'list'>
           <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

It is a ndarray with lists of lists of strings.

I'm using the following code to create the same structure, a list of lists of lists of strings and trying to convert the outermost list into a ndarray **without also converting the inner lists into ndarrays**.

```
captions = []
for row in attrs.iterrows():

    sorted_row = row[1].sort_values(ascending=False)

    attributes, variations = [], []
    for col, val in sorted_row[:20].iteritems():
        attributes.append([x[1] for x in word2Id if x[0] == col][0])
    variations.append(attributes)

    for i in range(9):
        variations.append(random.sample(attributes, len(attributes)))

    captions.append(variations)

np.save('train_captions.npy', captions)
```

When I open the resulting `npy` file, the class hierarchy is like this:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
        <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
           <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

How can I store `captions` in the code above so that it has the same structure as the file at the very top.

Comment: `np.save` can only save numpy arrays.  When given the list, it first does `np.array(captions)`.  That turns the nested lists into a multidimensional array.  Constructing an array of lists is tricky, especially if the lists all have the same size. Look at the array `dtype` and `shape` rather than the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to replicate your code (more or less):

```
In [273]: captions = []
In [274]: for r in range(2):
     ...:     attributes, variations = [], []
     ...:     for c in range(2):
     ...:         attributes.append([i for i in ['a','b','c']])
     ...:     variations.append(attributes)
     ...:     for i in range(2):
     ...:         variations.append(random.sample(attributes, len(attributes)))
     ...:     captions.append(variations)
     ...:         
In [275]: captions
Out[275]: 
[[[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]],
 [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]]]
```

The list has several levels of nesting.  When passed to `np.array`, the result is a 4d array of strings:

```
In [276]: arr = np.array(captions)
In [277]: arr.shape
Out[277]: (2, 3, 2, 3)
In [278]: arr.dtype
Out[278]: dtype('<U1')
```

Where possible `np.array` tries to make as high dimensional array as it can.

To make an array of lists, we have to do something like:

```
In [279]: arr = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
In [280]: arr[0] = captions[0]
In [281]: arr[1] = captions[1]
In [282]: arr
Out[282]: 
array([list([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]]),
       list([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]])],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, using the nested ndarrays works fine for the model I'm training anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
np.save('list.npy', list)
read_list = np.load('list.npy').tolist()
print(read_list, type(read_list))

>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] <class 'list'>
```

If we don't use `.tolist()` the result is:

```
['a' 'b' 'c' 'd'] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```